# Overriding fullcalendar.css to create custom look of event in fullcalendar

Tags: html, css, fullcalendar

I have created a custom css file 'fullcalendar-custom.css' to override the css of the events so that they have a specific look inside the day window.
The look I want for an event is defined below:

1. No radius around the event. - did that...
2. The event resides at the bottom of the day window, not in the middle of the window, which is the default.
3. The event has a height that is 1/3 the size of the day window. Right now, with a single line of text the events height is as high as the text. I want it to have a larger height.

right now my custom css file only has the radius removed.

```js
.fc-event {
    border-radius: 0;
}
```

Here are the elements I'm trying to modify but not sure how.
[image]
[image]

Not sure what to change here in the css
[image]

Comment: Is this live? It would make life a lot easier to provide optimization details and the CSS you need.

Comment: no, it's just a project I'm working on. What do you mean by optimization details?